# Count Number of Pages in Salesforce Files

Tags: apex, pdf, files, contentdocument

Is there any way to count the number of pages in apex if a file of PDF type is stored in Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding this is not directly available in Salesforce. But if you can do alternative ways -

1. Use JS with pdf2 JSON and get the count - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30132117

Added code here for direct reference from above link -

```js
var PDFParser = require('pdf2json');
var pdfParser = new PDFParser();

pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataReady', function(data) {
    var doc = data.PDFJS && data.PDFJS.pdfDocument && data.PDFJS.pdfDocument.numPages;
    console.log('Number of pages:', doc);
});
// pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataError', _.bind(_onPFBinDataError, self));

pdfParser.loadPDF('test.pdf');
```

2. Have an API with node/php which has this capability and whenever you're storing the file send the file to that api and store count along with.
3. Have a Salesforce evergreen functions(which allow to use native technology with salesforce) and from that you can use node js or other scripting language.