# Count the number of pages of a PDF stored as an Attachment from Apex code

Tags: apex, soql, attachment

Is there a way to get the count of pages in an Attachment?

```
List<Attachment> attachments = [SELECT Id, Body FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :myRecord];
```

I am using this SOQL to get the Body, but need the number of pages of the Attachment along with it.

Comment: There is no native support from Salesforce platform for this. You can check this [SFSE link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321853/count-number-of-pages-in-salesforce-files) on an alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually read the page while being uploaded and use native javascript to fetch the count of pages and push it in a custom field on Content version.

For eg (With VF page).

```
<apex:page id="pdfUploader">
    <script>
        function readFile(input){
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
            reader.onloadend = function(){
                const count = reader.result.match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g).length;
                console.log('Number of Pages:',count );
            }
        }
    </script>
    <input type="file" onchange="readFile(this)"/>
</apex:page>
```

If its not a custom UI from where you upload the files, then you need to create an intermediate Visualforce page in Apex, to show the pdf and run the same javascript logic to fetch the count and use `sforce` api to update the count from Javascript end.